# Weight of the most probable configuration

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability

In Statistical mechanics, when we are to find the most probable configuration for the assembly using Lagrange undetermined multiplier method, why it is convenient to maximize $\log(W)$ instead of $W$, where $W$ is the weight of the configuration.

$$dW + adN + bdE = 0$$

$$ d logW + \alpha dN + \beta dE = 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In order to avoid using quotient rule while taking derivative.
2. In order to use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: I think that an illustration of points 1 and 2 would increase the quality of your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.